# Creating workgroups in MsAccess 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ddl

I want to create workgroups in my database in MS Access 2010 such that I can provide different access levels to different users.

I tried using DDL commands creating user by `CREATE USER` and `CREATE GROUP` but I am getting syntax error stating that **error in create table**

Please suggest me some way so that I can provide authorization and authentication to my Database in MS Access 2010 (.accdb file).

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: You may wish to consider SQL Server Express 2012 for a back-end to MS Access http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User level security is a feature provided by the Jet database engine.  Support for that feature was dropped from the new ACE database engine when using the new ACCDB format database.  However it is still supported with the older MDB format databases.

So, if you want user level security with Access 2010, create an MDB format database and use that.

Comment: Is there any other way out...like creating users and groups for DB using sql queries??

Comment: Not with an ACCDB format database.  You must either switch to MDB or create you own system for an ACCDB.  But any system you create for ACCDB will not be managed by Access, so you'll have to do all that, too.